# SELECT statement won't return row first time after INSERT commit transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have two stored procedures, one `AddReportsApi` for inserting data with a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, and the other `GetReportsApi` for selecting the data for inserted row.

I call the `INSERT` stored procedure first, then I call the `SELECT` stored procedure but sometimes it does not return any rows for the passed in `SearchItemId` which is used in the `WHERE` predicate.

If I execute the SELECT stored procedure a second time, it returns the expected rows.

Is there a delay in inserting the data to the table? Please note that the stored procedures are called from HangFire background job framework. From my test, HangFire should not affect the INSERT and SELECT stored procedure calls. The INSERT stored procedure is called multiple times within a minute to insert the records into the ReprotsApi table.

Insert stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddReportsApi]       
   @OrderID nvarchar(50),
   @SearchItemId nvarchar(50),
   @SubjectID nvarchar(50),
   @SearchType nvarchar(50),
   @ApiName nvarchar(50),
   @ApiRequest text,
   @ApiResponse text,
   @IsActive bit,
   @CreatedOn datetime,
   @CreatedBy nvarchar(50),
   @ModifyOn datetime,
   @ModifyBy nvarchar(50),
   @HitType nvarchar(2)    
AS    
BEGIN    
   SET NOCOUNT ON;    

   BEGIN TRANSACTION  
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[ReportsApi] ([OrderID], [SearchItemId], [SubjectID], [SearchType],    
                                       [ApiName], [ApiRequest], [ApiResponse], [IsActive],
                                       [CreatedOn], [CreatedBy],
                                       [ModifyOn], [ModifyBy], [HitType])    
       VALUES (@OrderID, @SearchItemId, @SubjectID, @SearchType,
               @ApiName, @ApiRequest, @ApiResponse, @IsActive,
               @CreatedOn, @CreatedBy,
               @ModifyOn, @ModifyBy, @HitType)    

       IF (@@ERROR != 0)    
       BEGIN    
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
       END    
       ELSE    
           COMMIT TRANSACTION  
END
```

SELECT stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReportsApi]         
   @OrderID nvarchar(50)      
  ,@SearchItemId nvarchar(50)      
  ,@SubjectID nvarchar(50)    
  ,@CreatedBy nvarchar(50)      
AS      
BEGIN           
 SET NOCOUNT ON;      



 SELECT [Id]      
      ,[OrderID]      
      ,[SearchItemId]      
      ,[SubjectID]      
      ,[SearchType]      
      ,[ApiName]      
      ,[ApiRequest]      
      ,[ApiResponse]      
      ,[IsActive]      
      ,[CreatedOn]      
      ,[CreatedBy]      
      ,[ModifyOn]      
      ,[ModifyBy]      
      ,[HitType]      
  FROM [dbo].[ReportsApi] WHERE  [SearchItemId] = @SearchItemId
END
```

Comment: I'd really recommend "upgrading" to `TRY...CATCH` methodology here.

Comment: Also, out of interesting, why `INSERT` all that data and then `SELECT` it back in another SP? The application already has the information as it inserted it all.

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling the stored procedures?

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer your question, but is a transaction even needed here? I only see a single atomic operation. It's not like the record will ever get partially inserted.

Comment: There are four parameters in the second SP but you use only one. Probably this is just a part of the whole sp. But it is this part that fails. Perhaps we need to see the whole picture to understand your problem

Comment: There are two issues. 1) SQL Server is multi-threaded and Selects/Inserts are performed in parallel.  When You do a Select data isn't returned in same order every time and you must use an OrderBy to always get data ion same order. 2) SQL Server allows multiple users so when new data is added using a key like ID you can't take the highest number and add one.  Another user can simultaneously be doing the same.  So when you need unique ID you should have a stored procedure to get next ID and use a lock so only one user can get new ID to prevent duplicates or skipping numbers.

Comment: Tell us more about your use of Hangfire - does the SELECT happen on the same background process as the INSERTS as a continuation?

Comment: @StewartRitchie There are two methods. First job calls the INSERT stored procedure, then the second job calls the SELECT stored procedure after the first job is completed. The second job is called using BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith.

Comment: Right, so does each of these jobs establish it's own independent db connection? My thought is that if they use different connections, there's no reason why the two commands would be batched together and it would be susceptible to a race-condition.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because indexes are being rebuilt under the hood after the insert completes.
This can give dirty/phantom reads.
If you have an index on [SearchItemId]  then the 2nd query might use this but the index may still being refreshed.

This can even affect clustered indexes if you are inserting into the middle of the B-Tree.

It might be worth sticking a sleep(10000) or WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'; into your code...
(That's 10 sec but you could experiment with different timings.)

Good luck!